# how to check data if exists "type of table" in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a type in sql server 2008 for to pass datatable to stored procedure.
My SP works ok but how can I check data if exists in the table?
**(for example: check detailid or id
if exists: update them 
if not exists: insert new )**

here is my SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Data]
(
    @empinfo myType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Insert into TableEmp(ID, DetailID, Text)
select id, detailid, text from @empinfo

END
```

Thnx all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Data]
(
    @empinfo myType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


MERGE TableEmp AS t
USING (select id, detailid, [text] from @empinfo) AS s
ON s.ID = t.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET t.detailid = s.detailid,
               t.[text] = s.[text]

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(id, detailid, [text])
VALUES(s.id, s.detailid, s.[text]);

END
```

Comment: Is there a problem on update? cause inserting is OK but update is not.
Thnx

Comment: why what is the problem ?

Comment: +1 But using `MERGE` doesn't avoid a race condition. We need to add `HOLDLOCK` to avoid this problem. Please reads this [article wrote by Dan Guzman](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean on it now :)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean wow cheers pal, never thought of these issue very interesting read, thanks a lot for sharing pal.

Comment: My main problem is, I am trying to insert or update checked checkboxes into db. so if the user first time checked 3 checkboxes and after awhile the user added 2 more so I have to get 5 checked values then in db I have to add 2 more next to 3. I have to delete current 3 then have to add 5 of them or have to add 2 more except 3.
thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable and count the records in the table.

```
DECLARE @count INT

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(ID)
              FROM TableEmp)

-- Do Something with the results
```

So then using conditional logic, you can do something with the count to accomplish different results.

```
IF @count = 0
BEGIN
    -- Do Something cool like insert data
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- Do Something else like update data
END
```

This is a simple example where you can search for a specific record and update it.  If you need to update many records, then you can use cursors and iterate through the required records and update what you need.

More information about cursors can be found here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: I have to update also many records. And people say "use cursor less".And I also really don t know about cursor.
Thnx